# Changing user control css class in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

So I have a user control that displays links and I want to change the color of the link that is currently active. 
This is the code inside my ListView of my usercontrol ascx file.

```
<asp:ListView ID="sidebarListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSidebar" OnItemCommand="sidebarListView_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
  <div id="sidebarItemID" class="sidebarItem" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
     </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
....
```

I need to change the sidebarItemID class when the linkbutton is clicked.
My default.aspx code behind looks like this:

```
private void SideBar1_ItemCommand ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
  Int32 facId = Sidebar1.FacultyId;
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Id], [Name], [Faculty_Id], [User_Id], [Author], [Picture], [Location] FROM [Books] WHERE [Faculty_Id]=" + facId + " ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC";
  HtmlGenericControl htmlDivControl = (HtmlGenericControl) FindControlRecursive( Sidebar1 , "sidebarItemID" );
  htmlDivControl.Attributes.Add("class", "sidebarItemActive");
  string newClass = htmlDivControl.Attributes["class"];
  //Response.Write( String.Format( "<script>alert('{0}');</script>" , newClass ) );
}
```

This correctly changes the sqlDataSource based on the ID of the link clicked in the user control. However the class doesn't change.

If I uncomment the Response.Write(...) section it correctly gives an alert that says "sidebarItemActive" so it correctly finds the control from my page and assigns its class attribute as "sidebarItemActive" but nothing changes on the page if I view the page source in the browser it says the class is still "sidebarItem".
What is going on here that the change does not come into effect?

Comment: Perhaps the attribute already exists and adding it doesn't take effect as you wish? Try `htmlDivControl.Attributes["class"] = "sidebarItemActive";` EDIT: That actually probably won't work. Check that the ID of the div on the page is actually sidebarItemID, because controls can append their control name to the id.

Comment: I tried it, same thing. Besides as far as i know Add acts the same as Put, so it replaces the value if it is already set.

Comment: Hmm. On the page, the ID is indeed not "SidebarItemID" but rather "sidebar_Sidebar1_sidebarListView_sidebarItemID_0" etc. But How does the findcontrol method actually find the element then? Also if i set the user controls ClientIDMode as static it still doesnt work, but all the items in the ListView have the same ID, but the class still does not change

Comment: I think this has to do with the page lifecycle. Postbacks are handled before renders, and since you're using a template for your div, the actual set of sidebar divs is created after your code is handled. Try doing this on Render of the control . If this works as I hope it should, I'll submit it as an answer

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that I understand. Basically, I can't do it on the render of the control, because when the control is rendered I don't need the class to change. I need it changed when the user clicks a link in the control. Did I understand you correctly? And thanks for helping

Comment: Essentially, what the life cycle states is that when you handle a click event, the page fires all events, including Load, then postback events like click events, then calls render on all controls. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx. So basically what I'm saying is that the render probably undoes whatever you did in the ItemCommand. You can perhaps set some state variable or something of that ilk to have the render happen properly, or you can try using AJAX and Javascript to make what you want happen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13181/discussion-between-dmi-and-joonasl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved the problem by defining the ListViews ItemDataBound event handler and assigning the css class in there. The problem previously was, that since my controls were inside updatePanels the ItemDataBound event was not firing. I had to manually call "DataBind()" inside the click method.

Inside my default.aspx

```
// Exposed click event, updates RecentBooks control sqlDataSource.
private void SidebarItems1_Clicked ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
  RecentBooks1.updateDataSource( SidebarItems1.FacultyId.ToString() );
  SidebarItems1.DataBind();
```

}

Inside my user control.ascx

```
protected void sidebarListView_ItemDataBound ( object sender , ListViewItemEventArgs e ) {
  LinkButton button = e.Item.FindControl( "NameLabel" ) as LinkButton;
  if (FacultyName != null && button != null) {
     if ( button.Text == FacultyName ) {
        button.CssClass = "sidebarItemActive";
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual `<div>`s on your page are generated during the Render state of the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). This happens after the Control event handling stage, thus any changes you make to the HTML during your handler function are effectively undone during Render, as the control's HTML is regenerated from the template. To have the control change its internal HTML in this case, you may put your update code in an overridden Render function for your control. The MSDN has an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.render.aspx) of how to write the render function.